# UrlFetchApp.fetch() Exception: DNS error in Google Forms Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, amazon-elb

I've attached the following code to a Submit Button in Google Forms:

```
function generateQueryString(data) {
   const params = [];
   for (var d in data)
      params.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
   return  params.join('&');
}

function ctrlqFormSubmit(event) {
  // The event is a FormResponse object:
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response
  var formResponse = event.response;
  // Gets all ItemResponses contained in the form response
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses()
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  // Gets the actual response strings from the array of ItemResponses
  var responses = itemResponses.map(function getResponse(e) { return e.getResponse(); });
  // Post the payload as JSON to our Cloud Function
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://<**MY DOMAIN HERE**:3001>/formdir?' + generateQueryString(responses));
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Unfortunately, the Trigger fails with the message:

```
Exception: DNS error: http://**MY DOMAIN HERE**:3001/formdir?0=Name&1=&2=Biz&3=Research&4=&5=&6=&7=&8=Other&9=&10=&11=&12=&13=&14=
    at ctrlqFormSubmit(SubmitFcn:18:30)
```

But if I copy this exact string in my browser, I get the expected result.  Also, when I use NSLOOKUP with this domain on the command line, the IP's return as expected. The domain even resolves when I go to `https://dns.google/...`

The text of error itself seems to indicate the function is working, and it's a GET request, which is why I'm using Query Parameters, but the DNS name is not resolving in the script. I even used one of the IPs and got the same error.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for commenting!  I should have added above that "my domain" is in fact publicly-facing.  But I think I found the answer: I got the DNS error probably because of what happened NEXT...the redirect I had in place from the public domain to my internal network domain (using AWS's Application Load Balancer)!  Since the browser was able to handle the redirect, I expected the script to do so as well.  Anyway, I changed from the "redirect" to "forward"...and it seems to be working now.

Comment: @ShawnKimsey Add it as a answer in the answer box below or delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: Even though the domain used above was public-facing, the AWS Load Balancer it uses was configured with a "REDIRECT" to an internal domain.  It was this second domain that caused the DNS Error, even though the message references the external domain. I changed the load balancer action from "redirect" to "forward", and now all is well.